# Spring RedisTemplate: after 8 calls method keys hangs up

Tags: java, spring, redis

I use Spring RedisTemplate (spring-data-redis 1.7.1) for communication with Redis. I need to get and then delete keys by regexp (ex: "context:user1:*"). I use method *"RedisTemplate.keys(...)"* for getting array of keys

```
{
    String key = String.format("%s:%s:%s", context, userId,"*");
    Set<byte[]> keys = redisTemplate.getConnectionFactory().getConnection().keys(key.getBytes());
    logger.debug(String.format("test log"));
}
```

But on 8-9 iteration call restTemplates.keys(...) stops execution of the my java service. The call of method is not returned from framework. My service is hangs up. Also it is happening everytime. Workaround is only restart my service.

Comment: Can you elaborate on `But on 8-9 iteration, call restTemplates.keys(...) stops execution of the my java service.` . Does the browser just keeps loading?

Comment: yes, after 8-9 calls of   redisTemplate.getConnectionFactory().getConnection().keys(key.getBytes()); my service keeps loading

Comment: You are presuming that you will find the key, why is that. What if the key is not found. Secondly where is the code where you get the keys.getBytes?  Just try to get the key first, check if its null or not, and then try. Can you also enable debug logging for redis?

Comment: Log of Redis monitor (7 times): [0 127.0.0.1:54892] "KEYS" "DIALOG:test:*"

Comment: If i remove loop with redisTemplate.delete, it also happening. If i will not find keys, then just Set<byte[]> keys will be null. But i does not return anything from redisTempate.keys(). My service is hangs up and i need to restart it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you're using Jedis with pooling, you run into an exhaustion of the underlying connection pool.

Each call to `redisTemplate.getConnectionFactory().getConnection()` allocates a new connection from the connection pool. Do you call `connection.close()`?. If not, the pool gets exhausted. The pools starts to block your request (hoping another thread will return a connection so it can be used by the thread which requests a connection).

Comment: Thank you. I also change redisTemplate.getConnectionFactory().getConnection().keys(...) to redisTemplate.keys(..)