# Spring jedis get key list return empty

Tags: java, spring, redis, jedis

I am trying to get key list from redis but it isn't work.

```
    @Autowired
    org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate redisTemplate;

    redisTemplate.opsForValue().set("test","test");
    redisTemplate.opsForValue().set("t:test","test");
    redisTemplate.opsForValue().set("t::test1","test");
    redisTemplate.opsForValue().set("t1.t2::test2","test");
    Set<String> keys = redisTemplate.keys("t*");
```

I've tried different patterns for keys "*", "t:*","t::*". Nothing works. 
Only if I write full key name it works.

Creating bean code:

```
@Bean
RedisTemplate<String,Object> redisTemplate(@Autowired JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory){
    RedisTemplate<String,Object> template=new RedisTemplate<>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory);
    return template;
}

@Bean
JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory(@Value("${redis.host:192.168.99.100}") String host, @Value("${redis.port:6379}") int port, @Value("${redis.password:}") String password){
    RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(host, port);
    redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPassword(RedisPassword.of(password));
    return new JedisConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration);
}
```

Comment: You should have configured redisTemplate with StringRedisSerializer in your bean  redisTemplate.setDefaultSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());

Comment: Many answers for a similar question are discussed under another SO post. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098079/how-to-get-all-keys-from-redis-using-redis-template

Comment: Thanks @GovindParashar. Solved problem by adding key serializer.
template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add key Serializer.

```
template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
```