# Check if redis key is hash or string using restTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, redis

I have Redis DB consisting of hashes and strings.

I got all keys from DB using this code:

```
        Set<byte[]> keys = redisTemplate.getConnectionFactory().getConnection().keys("*".getBytes());

        Iterator<byte[]> it = keys.iterator();

        while(it.hasNext()){

            byte[] data = (byte[])it.next();

            String key = (new String(data, 0, data.length));
            System.out.println(key);
        }
```

from here: [How to get all Keys from Redis using redis template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098079/how-to-get-all-keys-from-redis-using-redis-template)

Since the key can be hash or string, how to determine when I can use opsForHash and opsForValue i.e. how to check if it is hash or it is a string in spring boot using **restTemplate**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Redis command to get the type of a key is `TYPE`: https://redis.io/commands/type

You can use RedisTemplate's `public DataType type(K key)` method to execute this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/RedisTemplate.html#type-K-

Here's an example:

```
Set<byte[]> keys = redisTemplate.getConnectionFactory().getConnection().keys("*".getBytes());

Iterator<byte[]> it = keys.iterator();

while(it.hasNext()){
    byte[] data = (byte[])it.next();
    String key = (new String(data, 0, data.length));

    DataType type = redisTemplate.type(key);

    if (type == DataType.HASH) {
       // ...
    } else if (type == DataType.STRING) {
       // ...
    }
}
```

Edit: one more piece of advice is that you may want to use `SCAN` instead of `KEYS *` (mentioned in one answer to the SO question you linked). Scan is generally better in production since it doesn't try to get and return all keys at once.